# What does un mean in the column for immigration year on the 1920 US census?

Tags: united-states, census-records, immigration

What does un mean in the column for immigration year on the 1920 United States census? Other people have a year entered.

Comment: "un" could be "unknown". Can you give an example, so we can look at it?

Answer (score 6):

The "[Instructions to Enumerators](https://www.lib.ncsu.edu/documents/guides/popcensus/images/1920enu.pdf)" for the 1920 census include the following instruction in the second paragraph, titled **Definite answers**:

> **Definite answers** - Try to get a definite answer to each inquiry according to the instructions herein given. But if *after every effort* you can not obtain the desired information write "Un" (for unknown).